# Does it makes sense to calculate a correlation between two binary variables?

Tags: r, correlation, binary-data

I have a data set with 14 binary variables. I conducted a survey and there was a question with 14 elements of a specific method to which the respondents had to check if they used the element. Now I would like to know if it were the same people that ticked off fewer boxes for certain elements.

I thought about using the Pearson correlation (or phi coefficients), but I don't know if it makes sense to use this method. I also read about similarity methods, but I don't know if a similarity matrix gives the appropriate response to my question.

Furthermore, when I used the cor(df) function, I got some NA's because one variabele has all 1's because all the respondents used this element... How should I solve this problem?

Can someone help me?

My data looks like this:

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  X4 ...
1   1   1   0   1  ...
0   0   1   0   1  
1   1   1   0   1  
1   1   1   0   1
1   1   1   0   1
1   0   1   1   1
0   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   0   1
1   1   1   0   1
...
```

Comment: You can take a look here:  http://www.statisticshowto.com/phi-coefficient-mean-square-contingency-coefficient/ and here: http://www.statisticshowto.com/tetrachoric-correlation/ . However, I wouldn't use $X_4$ because, in your sample, it is not really a variable (it is constant) so it doesn't make any sense to reason in terms of covariance/correlation/association with other variables.

Comment: `if it were the same people that ticked off fewer boxes for certain elements` I'm sorry for not understanding this enough. Can you explain more clearly what you want to test or to measure?

Comment: @ttnphns Each variable (X1, X2...) represents an element of the the project management method Scrum. I asked the respondents to tick off the elements they used in their project. In the analysis I saw that there were some elements which aren't used by more than half of the respondents. I would like to know if it were the same (or more or less the same) people who didn't use these different elements. I thought if I correlate for example 2 of these less frequent elements, I could find out if it were the same people. Does this makes it more clear to you?

Comment: @FedericoTedeschi I read the two links you posted. So you suggest that I should use a Tetrachoric correlation matrix?

Comment: Yes, if your focus is just on the correlation between couples of variables and the assumption that each binary variable has an underlying normal distribution (as in the probit model) makes sense. Otherwise, I think the phi coefficient would be ok. However, you could be interested not in couples, but on group on variables. In this case, you could consider other techniques, like multiple correspondance analysis (or other possibilities to extend factor analysis to binary variables). If your focus is on classifying individuals based on values on such variables, you could use cluster analysis.

Comment: Anthony, I see. You could do cluster analysis of items (based on some distance, similarity or correlation measure between them. There are dosens of different measures for binary data to choose from. Another option might be identifying patterns of "missingness" performed in Missing Value analysis.

Comment: @FedericoTedeschi Thanks for your answer, but I would like to know it for each couple of variables, because I can't just select few of them in my report. ( I need a matrix.. my supervisor told me this.) Furthermore, how can I know if the variables have an underlying normal distribution? (I just listed the elements of the scrum method as variables..). The only goal I have is to find out if it are (more or less) the same people who haven't ticked off some variables. So you think it's ok if I use the Phi coefficient? But then I get the problem with NA for the variables which only have 1's.

Comment: I chose to do a Pearson correlation, and I added a row containing all zero's for the NA problem. I used the corr.test() function in R which also gave me the (corrected (by Holm's) p-values). I hope this is good enough for the purpose of my study. Thank you all for the answers! Much appreciated and I learned a lot of new things today ;)

Comment: I'm not suggesting you to select a few variables. I think that the amount of data you would present by using either cluster analysis or some technique similar to factor analysis would be reduced, but no variable would be excluded. Do you need a matrix with pairs of variables or any matrix is ok? And why do you need it? As for the normal distribution: the idea is that there is an unobservable propensity to use the element, and that you actually use it only if you overcome a given threshold in such propensity.

Comment: If your goal is to see whether the same people who did not use a given element also did not use another one, why should you exclude methods considering all variables together? You could come up with results as: "people who used 1, 2 and 4 are more or less the same, as well as people using 3, 5 and 6". Also, you should report which variables have all $0$'s or all $1$'s, but then exclude them by multivariable analysis, since it doesn't make any sense to see how much they are associated with other variables.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoTedeschi. The thing is that I don't know a lot about clustering. But I will try to figure it out and implement it.